# How do I get items from one character to another?

Tags: diablo-ii

While I was playing Sorceress, I picked up a unique shield, but want my Paladin to use it. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the stash is shared between characters like it is in D3. **So how do I swap out items between my characters?** Or am I just S.O.L?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no non-modded in-game method to transfer gear by yourself from one character to another.

There are two separate methods that I know of that can be used.

1. By default, Diablo 2 restricts itself to a single instance.  By replacing the d2gfx.dll with a patched one, you can run multiple instances.  **Warning:** Do NOT use this to play online; you will probably be banned.  If you play online, you already have the tools available to transfer items.

   By running multiple instances, you can create your own TCP/IP games with one character, join with the other, and transfer as usual.
2. Use an offline tool to transfer items between characters, such as [ATMA](http://atma.incgamers.com/).

Personally, I'd recommend option 2; this is much more convenient than having multiple instances open and having to switch back and forth.

Comment: Can I play TCP/IP with the same cd-key? I have 2 PC's so if I installed it on both and copied my save file over, could I do it that way instead?

Comment: As long as you're not connecting to Bnet, I believe it should work.

Comment: The ATMA has **very poor virus rating score:** https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/54ece20bb125b7ba35a2e089ba057d6924014e78460e8f04bff28f3b74edbaf6/analysis/1419933357/ Can anybody ensure that file didn't harm his PC?

Answer (score 9):

### Battle.net Realms

The safest way to solo transfer items between characters ("muling") within one account is by creating a game (I recommended you create a game with a password, so no strangers or spam bots wander in) and waiting 5 minutes before dropping the item in game and logging in with another character to pick it up.

Once the game have been active (at least one player in the game) for over 5 minutes, [it will stay up for 5 minutes](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/faq/realms.shtml) even if there are no players in the game. If you change characters more than 4 times in less then 5 minutes you will receive a temporary ban ("Realm Down"), by the time you get back in after a temp ban your game will most likely have expired.

### Single Player

The easiest way to transfer items between character in single player, is to use a third part

You can use [ATMA](http://atma.incgamers.com/) or [GoMule](http://gomule.sourceforge.net/), both are a ways of moving items around (they include other feature such as a drop calculatir and unlimited stash capabilities). These programs (and other similar variants) allow a large number of items to be kept in stashes away from your D2 character. ATMA is the original muling utility and GoMule is a java-based utility that also works on Macs. Both programs not change the amount of space that you have in-game, it merely stores items (and gold) in a separate file.

To use the program with your single player characters:

1. Go into the "save" folder in your Diablo II folder (typically C:\Program Files\Diablo II).
2. Look for the .d2s file with the same name as your character
3. Load the file

Note: Symantec flags ATMA as a virus/adware. This is a false positive. This [post](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showpost.php?p=6588751&postcount=13) and this [post](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showpost.php?p=6588866&postcount=16) shows how to get around it.

As a precaution, backup your saves before you transfer any items.

Comment: For single-player: if you are wary of third-party software, which is very understandable, you can set up a copy of Diablo2 in a **virtual machine**, create a character there and host a multi-player game. Then, you can simply join this game from your main system any time you like. Of course, you would need to re-host the game if you had to shut the virtual machine down.

Answer (score 3):

The *only* way to swap items between characters is to join a multiplayer game. If the characters are on the same account, you will need someone else to hold the game for you while you switch characters. Alternatively, you could join a game in-progress with people actually playing and try to hide your goods somewhere. This comes with the obvious risks that the players could leave, ending the game, or they could find your items.

There is the option of making a game alone and trying to do a quick switch, remembering the name, but you are not guaranteed that the empty game will still exist when you come back. If it doesn't, your items are lost, so this isn't a very reliable method.

If your characters are single-player, you can still swap items by joining open Battle.net and trying one of the above options.

Comment: They are single-player only, can I create my own game on the Open Battle.net? I have never used it.